# Mock field injection using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

I Am new in JUnit PowerMockito. Am try to test a method inside a class.that class having an autowired filed.
Service Class

```
@Service
public class MyServiceRegistration
{


    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;


    public void register() throws xception
    {
    //Do some thing
    }
}
```

AppConfig

```
@Component
public class AppConfig
{
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String serverPort;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Test Class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ AppConfig.class })
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*" })
public class MyServiceRegistrationTest
{ 
    @InjectMocks
    MyServiceRegistration myServiceRegistration = new MyServiceRegistration();
    @Mock
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        PowerMockito.when(AppConfig.getApplicationName()).thenReturn("SomeValue");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public final void testRegister() throws Exception
    {

        myServiceRegistration.register();
    }
}
```

When I debug the code I can see that AppConfig is mocked. But the applicationName and serverPort fields are null.

debug screen

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you inject your mocks twice.

- First, they are injected by `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
- Second time, manually with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

You set the expectations on the first instance, and then overwrite the mocks, that is why the expectations aren't there.

To prove it

```java
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    PowerMockito.when(appConfig.getApplicationName()).thenReturn("SomeValue");
    AppConfig beforeInitMocks = appConfig;
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    AppConfig afterInitMocks = appConfig;
    System.out.println("Same object?: " + (beforeInitMocks == afterInitMocks));
}
```

Note: I believe there is a typo in your post, you should have `PowerMockito.when(appConfig.getApplicationName())` (with the lowercase `appConfig`)

Answer (score 0):

Moved

```
PowerMockito.when(AppConfig.getApplicationName()).thenReturn("SomeValue");
```

to `testRegister` method. Now its working.

Comment: That is a band aid. I think the answer by Lesiak is really getting to the real problem.